# wordpress add field to post_class

Tags: wordpress, class, post, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add a custom field to my article post but not sure how to add an additional class to it.

Currently the classes get pulled through like this `<?php post_class($classes); ?>`.

However I need to add a custom field to this as well. To demonstrate ive added a class= but this doesnt work as class= is being added twice.

```
<?php post_class($classes); ?> class="<?php the_field( "size" ); ?>
```

So i need post_class and the_field to work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answers but I've found a simple way to do this

```
<?php post_class(get_field('field_name')); ?>
```

Comment: This is the simplest, most straightforward way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two different way,

**First:-** Add following code in `theme's functions.php` file:

This will add your class where `post_class` is called.

```
function category_id_class($classes)
{
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'post')
    {
        $classes[] = get_field( "size" );;
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('post_class', 'category_id_class');
```

**Second:-** Add this following code directly into your page:-

```
$post_classes = get_post_class();
$post_classes= implode(' ', $post_classes);
echo 'class="'.$post_classes. the_field( "size" )'"';
```

Hope this will help you little bit.

Answer (score 0):

So why you could not do like this:

```
<?php post_class(the_field( "size" )); ?>
```

Because it is working like this:

```
<?php post_class('my_custom_class'); ?>
```